# How to navigate to location based on given latitude and longitude in Android

Tags: android, database, google-maps, gps

I got confused on how to solve this problem.
I need to develop and android application titled 'Local Food Finder'.

- in my application, user search a food that they want to eat
- my application will give the result by listing all the restaurant that provide the related food.
- user can choose the restaurant and user can go to the restaurant by using gps.
- I have collect all the restaurant location data (longitude & latitude)

After make some research and study, I think I need to use GPS code.
For now, I already have the location data (latitude and longitude) for every restaurant. 
But, I don't know where to place/store the data. Do I need to place it in database? So my application can retrieve the restaurant's location from the database.
And then after that, how can user go to the location using this longitude and latitude? What code I have to use..? I know I have to use Java code but I didn't find the example code...
Someone please help me. I am a android beginner. I really don't know how to settle this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the data in https://www.parse.com, because they support geospatial queries. 'give me all reastaurants matching food x near (lat,lon)'.

To get the device position you could use https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation. Is the simplest code that I found so far to do so.